# Reopens app after closes it does not restore data from archive

Tags: ios, objective-c

I archive the data to file in applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillTerminate and unarchive the data in applicationWillEnterForeground.

It works well when the app enters background and returns to foreground, e.g. user pressing HOME.  Data can be restored.

But when I closes the app on the iPhone and reopens the app, the data is not restored.  I suspect applicationWillEnterForeground is not called in this case or my archived files are deleted once I closed the app.

If I am not restoring data in the correct event block, which event should I catch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The app will run application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.